AWS auto scaling group - Health check grace period value reset
In AWS we have an autoscaling group setup for a load balancer. We were getting error messages when the auto scaling group tries to add another windows ec2 instance. (ELB health is failing or not available)
ELB would then keep showing that its trying to add a new instance, but failing.
I increased the auto scaling group health check grace period from 600 to 1200 as believed this was caused due to the server not having enough time to initialise before health checks began. After a few minutes the new instance was added successfully.
This all seemed fine for a few days until it started happening again. When i checked the settings, the health check grace period had gone back to 600.
Is there any reason why this would happen? This is the same auto scaling group as i can see it was created years ago.
If I check the auto scaling group resource in AWS config, the value shows as 600 even though I have changed it again.
The only other thing I noticed is that the launch template the auto scaling group uses, was auto updated to a new version with a new AMI around the same time the value was reverted.
Thanks

It looks like you might have some Infrastructure as Code (IaC) tool that is overriding your changes.
If you're using tools like AWS CDK, Terraform (OpenTofu), or Pulumi, try changing the value there.
If not, and your resources were created using a CloudFormation stack, check the drift status to see if there have been any changes.
If none of these apply, you could check the CloudTrail logs to determine who or what is changing this value. This might help identify the source of the change.

Thanks you for the reply. I can see from the CloudTrail logs that it is elasticbeanstalk that is making the change. This is happening when the managed updates for the windows server is running.
It will send a request to update the autoscaling group launch template version to the latest, however it is also sending a request to set the healthCheckGracePeriod to 600.
